# split edge at multiple points without distorting uv or other data

Tags: edges, geometry, bmesh

Here's a bmesh edge:

```
+-----------------------------+
```

Say I want to cut it at multiple points, in the middle and 3/4 from the end like so:

```
+--------------+-------+------+
```

In which case I can use bmesh.ops.split_edges twice, as it cuts edges exactly in half.

But what if I want to split it at 3/5 from the end just to be awkward, without distorting the uv or other data that may be linearly interpolated between the 2 points?

split_edges doesn't allow this, and neither does loopcut_slide.

The only solution to this I've found is to use bmesh.ops.bisect_plane repeatedly.
It get's messy and rather complex though when I want to split one edge in lots of places, having to refactor the new edges into the algorithm after every cut.

I don't suppose there's a simpler / better way of doing this?